# Array only printing final element JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, listings

```
private static String[] nameArray;

public static void newPerson() {
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.print("Name: ");
 name = scanner.nextLine();
 nameArray = new String[] {
  name
 };

}

public static void personInfo() {
 System.out.print("Current Persons : \n");
 StringBuilder arrayOutput = new StringBuilder();

 for (String something: nameArray) {
  arrayOutput.append(something);
 }

 String text = arrayOutput.toString();
 System.out.println(text);
}
```

Hello all thanks in advance for your help I m having a problem I have a loop that call a method once a number is entered in that method is this:

So my question whenever I call the newPerson method and enter a name instead of having all the names stored and in the array and later printed, the personInfo method only prints the final name that I enter in the array why is it not displaying all the names?

Comment: public static void newPerson()
    {
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

           System.out.print("Name: ");
           name = scanner.nextLine(); 
           nameArray = new String[]{name};
          
    }

    public static void personInfo()
    {
   System.out.print("Current Persons : \n"); 
   StringBuilder arrayOutput = new StringBuilder();
      for ( String something  : nameArray) {
              arrayOutput.append(something);
      }  
        String text = arrayOutput.toString();
        System.out.println(text); 
     }

Comment: This doesn't look to be the complete code. Can you edit your question to show the complete code?

Comment: You're replacing the `nameArray` entirely after each input. You have to **add** it to your array. But it is easier to use 'ArrayList's in this case.

Comment: could you possibly illustrate how ? I have yet to use ArrayList

Comment: @TMichelsen, you're right... please make your comment an answer and fix the given code to work ... I'll vote for you ...

Comment: @Carlitos Way: Sure :-)

Comment: @TMichelsen, thanks ur answer was perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the nameArray entirely after each input. You have to add it to your array. But it is easier to use 'ArrayList's in this case.

Building on your provided code:

```
private static ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<>();

public static void newPerson() {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

       System.out.print("Name: ");
       name = scanner.nextLine(); 
       nameArray.add(name);
}

public static void personInfo() {
    System.out.print("Current Persons : \n"); 
    StringBuilder arrayOutput = new StringBuilder();
    for ( String something  : nameArray) {
        arrayOutput.append(something);
    }  
    String text = arrayOutput.toString();
    System.out.println(text); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you worked beautifully sorry about the noob question

Answer (score 1):

every time you are creating new string array with one element 
nameArray = new String[]{name};
so the latest one will be preserved which is your last element. So make sure that you are appending your names to nameArray.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use ArrayList if you are not sure the eventual size of the array.

```
private static List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void newPerson() {
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.print("Name: ");
 nameList.add(scanner.nextLine());
}

public static void personInfo() {
 System.out.print("Current Persons : \n");
 StringBuilder arrayOutput = new StringBuilder();

 for (String something: nameList) {
  arrayOutput.append(something);
 }

 String text = arrayOutput.toString();
 System.out.println(text);
}
```

You can still do it using array but you have to do lot of work during adding new element into array, probably you will need maintain the index for next insertion, provide initial size of array and in case it overflows then resize the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
nameArray = new String[]{name};
```

you are overriding the contents of `nameArray`, thus losing all previously saved names. `new String[]{name}` creates a new String array.

Use a list of String instead of an array and just add the new names to it.

```
// use List<String> instead of String[]
private static List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void newPerson() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();
    // add new names to list, old names will not be deleted 
    names.add(name);
}

public static void personInfo() {
    System.out.print("Current Persons : \n"); 
    StringBuilder arrayOutput = new StringBuilder();
    for(String something  : names) {
        arrayOutput.append(something);
    }  
    String text = arrayOutput.toString();
    System.out.println(text); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating and replacing an existing every time you take input from user . Replace that  add input in a list .